# How to live-stream video/audio to an online storage?

Tags: video-streaming, azure-storage, azure-mobile-services

I try to create an app that captures live video/audio on a Windows-10 phone device, and stream it as it's being captured to an Azure storage.

How can I create a program that will enable me to stream media from the client, and save it on the server side, as its coming?

I have two main problems -

1. How to create a program skeleton that will allow client-server communication from a Windows-10 client device to a server code running on Azure? (It's the same server code I mentioned that I need help with).
2. How to write a code on the server side, that will allow me to save the chunks of data as they're being streamed and come to the server to the same file?

   Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check out this tutorial: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-blob-storage/

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very general, and it seems that you are asking for guidance on design. Unfortunately, this type of question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

If you have specific questions as you are building your application, please ask them, and we will do our best to answer.